# Neo 6m outputting something i as a noob can't understand

Tags: arduino-uno, gps, eeprom, tinygps

So i connected my ublox neo 6m gps breakout board GY-GPS6MV2 to the arduino software serial and got this result, i used resistors and only supplied 3.3v to the board, gps encode library couldn't give me anything out of this. if possible please help and if this is the wrong forum please suggest a better one. also the board thinks that the date for some reason is Mar 17 2011 16:18:34*59. which is pretty wierd.

```
$GPTXT,01,01,02,HW UBX-G60xx 00040007 FFF9FFFFp*5D

$GPTXT,01,01,02,ROM CORE 7.03 (45969) Mar 17 2011 16:18:34*59

$GPTXT,01,01,02,ANTSUPERV=AC SD PDoS SR*20

$GPTXT,01,01,02,ANTSTATUS=DONTKNOW*33

$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53

$GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*3⸮$GPTXT,01,01,02,u-blox ag - www.u-blox.com*50

$GPTXT,01,01,02,HW UBX-G60xx 00040007 FFF9FFFFp*5D

$GPTXT,01,01,02,ROM CORE 7.03 (45969) Mar 17 2011 16:18:34*59

$GPTXT,01,01,02,ANTSUPERV=AC SD PDoS SR*20

$GPTXT,01,01,02,ANTSTATUS=DONTKNOW*33

$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53

$GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*3⸮$GPTXT,01,01,02,u-blox ag - www.u-blox.com*50

$⸮$GPTXT,01,01,02,u-blox ag - www.u-blox.com*50

$GPTXT,01,01,02,HW UBX-G60xx 00040007 FFF9FFFFp*⸮$GPTXT,01,01,02,u-blox ag - www.u-blox.com*50

$⸮$GPTXT,01,01,02,u-blox ag - www.u-blox.com*50

$GPTXT,01,01,02,HW UBX-G60xx 00040007 F⸮$GPTXT,01,01,02,u-blox ag - www.u-blox.com*50

$$GPTXT,01,01,02,u-blox ag - www.u-blox.com*50

$GPTXT,01,01,02,HW UBX-G60xx 00040007 FFF9FFFFp*5D

$GPTXT,01,01,02,ROM CORE 7.03 (45969) Mar 17 2011 16:18:34*59

$⸮$GPTXT,01,01,02,u-blox ag - www.u-blox.com*50

$GPTXT,01,01,02,HW UBX-G60xx 00040007 FFF9FFFFp*5D

$GPTXT,01,01,02,ROM CORE 7.03 (45969) Mar 17 2011 16:18:34*59

$GPTXT,01,01,02,ANTSUPERV=AC SD PDoS SR*20

$GPTXT,01,01,02,ANTSTATUS=DONTKNOW*33

$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53

$GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*30

$GPGGA,,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*48

$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*30

$GPGSV,1,1,00*79

$GPGLL,,,,,,V,N*64

$GPTXT,01,01,02,u-blox ag - www.u-blox.com*50
```

**Here is the full unedited output after 40 mins**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/148W_6shE0U2lprimApvtvG1i3Vf2-Izx/view?usp=sharing

edit:- i also connected the tx pin to the rx and vice versa and used a resistor as told by an tutorial on the tx pin from the arduino or the rx pin of the board. it is also sending many gptxt messages which some say on other forums are usally send when some error occurs or the board restarts. idk why it is coming on my board.

Comment: does anyone know anything i can do to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by " i used resistors and only supplied 3.3v to the board" ?

Comment: @Majenko i followed a tutorial which said me to attach 3.3v to vcc pin and use resistors on the tx pin which sends data from arduino.

Comment: Why do you think there's something wrong? What kind of output did you expect? The GPS is outputting NMEA data just like it's supposed to. It's not supposed to be human readable. You mention a date in 2011 but that's looks to be the date the ROM core was compiled, not wat the GPS thinks is the current date. Not weird at all. You need software to interpret the NMEA output, like TinyGPS. Try it.

Comment: @StarCat the gps is supposed to atleast give proper nema data and a nema lat long, but if you open the drive doc, the nema is just sending gptxt texts and most of the nema fields are empty. and tinygps just gives 0,0 at lat long and this is after keeping it on for 40 mins

Comment: That's because it probably does not have a fix yet. That may take a very long time and your GPS needs to have an unobstructed view of the sky. [Many "U-blox" GPS chips are fake](https://portal.u-blox.com/s/question/0D52p00008HKEEECA5/psa-fake-ublox-modules-and-potential-ways-to-identify-them) and can have all kinds of problems (like taking impossibly long to get a fix).

Comment: It looks to me like it's browning out and resetting repeatedly.

Comment: @Majenko yeah thats what i thought too. please help if you can

Comment: @StarCat the chip is real and i can assure you the chip is real.

Comment: @gamer1478 Ok, if you say so. Did you run checks to confirm it and did you buy it from a reputable seller? Do you have a link to where you bought it or do you have any documentation for the module? It looks like the power supply might be an issue. Maybe a photo of your setup might help.

Comment: @StarCat Yes. I bought 10 chips from the seller and the seller is reputable from china. I buy from him using alibaba. And all other chips are working and getting gps lock and data using the same circuit and Arduino. Due to the low value of 1 chip replacement is not an option as delivery value from india to china with export taxes is higher than the value of the chip. If possible please tell some way to fix this. My power supply is just normal Arduino Uno 3.3v supply. I can't share a photo due to some privacy concerns.

Comment: @StarCat I am very new to gps and gps chips but I am by no means new to coding or  arduino. I meant I am noob in like gps and stuff. I have used the gps chip also in my drone following a tutorial and it works absolutely fine there.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I'm asking because I know there are a lot of fakes around (have run into them myself). Is there any way you can check for a stable power supply or a marginal connection? Or do you have a schematic? It's hard to troubleshoot something that I can't see. If you say that all of the other chips you bought are functioning well, I would consider the possibility that this one is faulty. I know some GPS boards are 5V tolerant and have their own 3.3V stabilizer. Maybe yours is too?

Comment: @StarCat i have a GY-GPS6MV2 chip. this is the wiring-(https://www.xarg.org/image/GY-GPS6MV2.png) (but instead of vcc to 5v it is connected to  3.3v), many people online say that this breakout board is 5v tolerant and has an onboard regulator, haven't tested that yet but all other chips are working too, so it might be that this one is faulty. but i don't think so as this problem is pretty new to me, it is printing stuff in the console but has no data in it.

Comment: @StarCat thanks for help, someone on ublox portal recommended me to connect the boards vcc to 5v's and when i did that, it stopped rebooting, and after 20 mins got a lock, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

someone on ublox portal recommended me to connect the boards vcc to 5v's and when i did that, it stopped rebooting, and after 20 mins got a lock, thanks for your help.

the guy on ublox portal

> Post a photo of the board and a link of where you bought it so that we can point out that 5V is needed.
> The reboot symptom is usually caused by an inadequate voltage source --- when the 6m starts, current draw is low, when it finishes initial startup, it goes to work looking for sats and current draw jumps up. The higher current draw on a poor power source causes supply voltage to drop too.low which then causes the 6m to reset and restart and will happily repeat the cycle forever.
> Use a good DVM or oscilloscope to verify the inadequate voltage source.

after connecting the board to 5v supply the problem seemed to be fixed